# Android ImageView not loading

Tags: android, imageview

I tried to load image into ImageView by selecting from gallery or from camera,but unfortunately the  size is too high so i compressed it and tried to load it.But still the image does not load.I tried Picasso but I do not know how to load bitmap into ImageView using Picasso.Please help me with a solution.

Code:

```
fetch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
                    builder.setTitle("Select from");
                    builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            switch (which){
                                case 0:
                                    Intent takePicture = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                                    startActivityForResult(takePicture, 0);//zero can be replaced with any action code
                                    break;
                                case 1:
                                    Intent pickPhoto = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                                            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                                    startActivityForResult(pickPhoto , 1);//one can be replaced with any action code
                                    break;
                            }
                            alertDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                    alertDialog=builder.create();
                    alertDialog.show();

                }
            });

            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            switch (requestCode){
                case 0:
                    if (resultCode==RESULT_OK)
                    {

                        upld_img.setImageBitmap(compressImage(data.getData()));
                        Log.e("Image","Uploaded");
                    }
                    break;
                case 1:
                    if (resultCode==RESULT_OK)
                    {
                        upld_img.setImageBitmap(compressImage(data.getData()));
    //                    upld_img.setImageURI(data.getData());
                        Log.e("Image","Uploaded");
                    }
                    break;
            }

        }
        public Bitmap compressImage(Uri uri){
            InputStream inputStream=null;
            try{
                inputStream=getContext().getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
                ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                Bitmap bmp= BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100,byteArrayOutputStream);
                byteArrayOutputStream.close();
                inputStream.close();

            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException e){

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return bmp;
        }
```

ctgry_details_lyt.xml(id=upload_img):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="@dimen/hmpge_img_dimen"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/hmpge_img_dimen"
    android:id="@+id/upload_img"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/hmpge_img_mrgn"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/fetch"
        android:layout_below="@+id/upload_img"
        android:text="@string/fetch"
        android:textSize="@dimen/txt_sze"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/hmpge_img_mrgn"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/upload"
        android:layout_below="@+id/fetch"
        android:text="@string/upload"
        android:textSize="@dimen/txt_sze"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/hmpge_img_mrgn"/>
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/edt_txt_hght"
        android:background="@drawable/edtxt_bg"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:id="@+id/img_id"
        android:layout_below="@+id/upload"
        android:hint="@string/image_id"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/hmpge_img_mrgn"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/download"
        android:layout_below="@+id/img_id"
        android:text="@string/download"
        android:textSize="@dimen/txt_sze"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/hmpge_img_mrgn"/>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/download"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="@dimen/hmpge_img_dimen"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/hmpge_img_dimen"
        android:background="@drawable/user"
        android:id="@+id/dwnld_img"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/hmpge_img_mrgn"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/save"
            android:text="@string/save"
            android:textSize="@dimen/txt_sze"
            android:layout_below="@+id/dwnld_img"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/hmpge_img_mrgn"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Are yougetting any error?

Comment: Just image not being loaded

Comment: What is the value you are getting in data.getData()

Comment: Let me log..plzz wait..

Comment: content://media/external/images/media/45966

Comment: `I tried Picasso but I do not know how to load bitmap into ImageView using Picasso` did you check http://square.github.io/picasso/?

Comment: try this https://github.com/NileshJarad/ImagePicker

Comment: Can some one explain to me why it does not load

Comment: The Log below upld_img.setImageBitmap(compressImage(data.getData())); is executed though..

Comment: post xml code of upld_img. Looks like there is someproblem with layout

Comment: I have included the xml code

Answer (score 0):

You can directly load image using uri and picasso.

```
Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(data.getData()).into(upld_img);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try this,

Add below line in Your Manifest file inside

```
<application
....
android:largeHeap="true"
...
</application>
```

Because it can access large size of files,
Maybe it useful for you